# How do I create Oracle Function Index?

Tags: oracle, indexing

Just a simple question, How do I create a function based index on this query.

```
select * from mytable A where :var1 like A.fld1 || '%';
```

mytable has a normal, non-unique index on fld1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you *can* create a function-based index on the expression you've used in your query:

```
create index myindex on mytable (fld1 || '%');
```

However, it's unlikely to be of any benefit to this query. I'd say your normal non-unique index on fld1 will work just as well as the function-based index.

Comment: It's quite strange but not, normal non-unique index will NOT work as well as the FBI in this case. The author wants to find smaller strings in fields for a bigger value in var1. For example, if var1 is 'JohhDoe', one of right records will have 'John' or 'Jo' and so on.

Comment: Think about it, @knagaev. What if a row has fld1=`'%Johh'`... I'd be surprised if you could demonstrate that the FBI will make a repeatable, measurable difference to the query vs. the normal index.

Comment: Yes, @Jeffrey Kemp, you're right. I was confused by different behavior of '%' in operator || and operator LIKE. FBI is created as value of fld1 with hooked symbol '%' but LIKE interprets it as a wildcard. By the way, I doubt the normal index will be helpful anyway - only full scan is possible, huh?

Comment: Thanks for the replies :).. 

@knagaev

Yes, you are right, var1 has bigger value than on fld1.



I tried to create an index using the example given by Jeff, but still the optimizer didn't use the index. So I tried to force the cbo to use it using index hint. It worked, however the index wasn't helpful, FTS is still much faster. Any Ideas?

Comment: Ok, next step is to work out why it's slower than you expect it to be. How many records in `mytable`? How many records have a non-null `fld1`? How many records are returned by your test case? Also, do you *really* need to return all the columns (`*`)? Note: If your query is returning more than a small percentage of all the rows in the table, then a FTS is probably the best you can do anyway.

Comment: It seems to me that 'normal' index is useless in this case. And the matter is not in cardinality. I made a test on SQLFiddle. You can see in execution plans that "name like 'Joh%'" uses index, and "'John Doe' like name || '%'"doesn't use. The cardinality in both cases is the same - 1 record of 32769. It is enough for firm decision to use index. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/51201/2

Comment: Your SQL Fiddle is wrong. You have `select name from mytable...`, not `select * from mytable...`. These are very different scenarios.

Comment: Also, cardinality is key here. The number of rows which have a value vs. the number of rows that have NULL vs. the number of rows that have a matching value can make a huge difference to whether an index is useful or not. The number of blocks in the table can also make a huge difference. *Especially* if you are selecting all columns from the table vs. just the column from the index.

Comment: I finally got the index to work. The best it can do is a fast full scan which is not bad. Jeff is right, select "*" and "name" are two different scenarios. In my example, if I use select fld1 (where fld1 has an index), cbo uses FFS. If I add another field like fld2 (no index) to the query, it uses FTS. Columns from the index used in the select query is the key! Thanks so much guys!

Comment: Yep, FFS is your best bet (as David said) if you can avoid querying other columns. If you only need 1 or 2 other columns, you could add them to the index (makes the index bigger, but might still be faster than a FTS).

Comment: @JeffreyKemp My goal was to force using index. That's why I make "select name", not "select *". For optimizer didn't use the index in case of "'John Doe' like name || '%'" (see FTS in the plan) I drew a conclusion that the index can't be used at all. By the way FFS is not as good as an index can be used (range scan). I guess the author wanted to get range scan actually.

Comment: That's fine knagaev. And you're right, a range scan would obviously be better than a FFS, if it was even feasible for this query; but it isn't.

Answer (score 1):

You don't create a function-based index on a query, you create it on a function. What you have there is an operator, not a function.

What you want to do is find all rows in the table where fld1 matches the characters with which var1 begins, and the index that would helpyou with that is just one on fld1. It could be that the best plan you can hope of is a fast full index scan because this isn't really amenable to a range scan.

Comment: Thanks for the reply David. 

I see.. my problem is the optimizer doesn't seem to see the index as a good execution path. CBO doesn't use the index.